# How to properly validate user input and close Scanner?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm having a hard time figure out how to use the Scanner to correctly validate the user input and how to close the Scanner properly. I have tried placing `close()` function in multiple places. The output either closes to quickly, the output doesn't close at all or I get the error shown below.

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Currency;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Interest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        userInputCalculator();

    }

    private static double calculateInterest(double amount, double interestRate) {

        return (amount * (interestRate / 100));

    }

   public static void userInputCalculator() {

       try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
           System.out.println("Enter Loan Amount: ");
           while (sc.hasNextDouble()) {
               double amount = sc.nextDouble();
               if (amount > 0) {
                   Locale usa = new Locale("en", "US");
                   Currency dollars = Currency.getInstance(usa);
                   NumberFormat formatDollars = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(usa);
                   String amountPrint;
                   amountPrint = formatDollars.format(amount);

                   for (double interestRate = 2.0; interestRate <= 8.0; interestRate++) {
                       System.out.println(dollars.getDisplayName() + ": " + amountPrint + " at " + interestRate + "% = " + String.format("%.2f", calculateInterest(amount, interestRate)));
                   }
                   System.out.println("==== Going Backwards ====");
                   for (double interestRate = 8.0; interestRate >= 2.0; interestRate--) {
                       System.out.println(dollars.getDisplayName() + ": " + amountPrint + " at " + interestRate + "% = " + String.format("%.2f", calculateInterest(amount, interestRate)));

                   }
               } else {

                   System.out.println("You have entered an invalid amount. Please enter a dollar amount of one dollar or greater.");
                   System.out.println(amount);
                   System.out.println("Please enter a valid dollar amount: ");

               }
               sc.close();
           }

       }

   }
}
```

**Error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.ensureOpen(Scanner.java:1150)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.hasNext(Scanner.java:1540)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.hasNextDouble(Scanner.java:2514)
    at com.examples.exercises.section_5.Interest.userInputCalculator(Interest.java:26)
    at com.examples.exercises.section_5.Interest.main(Interest.java:12)
```

Comment: As it happens, a `Scanner` on `System.in` should not be closed

Comment: `Scanner` is tool for reading, not for validation. Also **do not** close `Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)`, it will close the underlying input stream as well, and you don't want to close `System.in`

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70867771/how-to-make-a-single-input-satisfy-2-scanners-at-the-same-time/70868080#70868080

Comment: Scanner was added so students could have an "easy" source of input.  (Well, and other people I suppose.)  Normally you want to close all input streams but in this case it's ok to make an exception.  As it's "easy mode" you're allowed to break a few rules.

Comment: Remove the `sc.close()` from your while loop. And although in general a `Scanner` should be closed, it should not be closed when it uses `System.in`.

Comment: In any case, the point of try-with-resources is that you don't have to manage the 'close' yourself.

Comment: Thank you everyone for responding. This has helped clear up my misconceptions on the topic.